# Read and change global std::map in executable through injected dll

Tags: c++, hook, detours

I have dll injected into executable with a few function hooks installed. 
Executable has global std::map variable, declared as

```
std::map<int, int> g_lenMap;
```

I know it's address from the disassembly. I need to insert key/value pair into this map (or somehow hook ::find() function, which looks much more different for me).

However, the most obvious way doesnt work:

```
std::map<int,int>* g_lenMap;
g_lenMap = (std::map<int,int> *) 0x4D7480;
int result = (*g_lenMap)[100];
```

It throws "map/set iterators incompatible" assert. I can easily read and change other global variables/structures, but not std::map. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling your DLL with *exactly* the same compiler/linker and STL as was used for the EXE? If not, you may be invoking an `operator[]` that expects a different data format that what was constructed by the EXE. You may be able to work around this by finding the `std::map`'s `operator[]` function dynamically in the EXE at run time and calling it.

Comment: Both are compiled with MS visual studio, but I am not sure about version. Thank you for your answer, I will try calling operator[].